# sqlite query to add index for results

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that include 2 parameters: group_id & name

```
CREATE TABLE inf_table (group_id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO  inf_table(group_id, name) values (1,'AA');
INSERT INTO  inf_table(group_id, name) values (1,'BB');
INSERT INTO  inf_table(group_id, name) values (1,'AB');
INSERT INTO  inf_table(group_id, name) values (2,'AA');
INSERT INTO  inf_table(group_id, name) values (2,'BA');
INSERT INTO  inf_table(group_id, name) values (2,'AB');
INSERT INTO  inf_table(group_id, name) values (2,'BB');
```

I run a query that order the result by group_id and then name. " select * from inf_table order by group_id,name;"
and got:

```
1|AA
1|AB
1|BB
2|AA
2|AA
2|BA
2|BB
```

But, I would like to add an index to each row that display the index of the name inside each group:

```
1|1|AA
2|1|AB
3|1|BB
1|2|AA
2|2|AA
3|2|BA
4|2|BB
```

How could I?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count rows that are in the same group and have a name before the current name:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM inf_table AS inf2
        WHERE inf2.group_id = inf_table.group_id
          AND inf2.name    <= inf_table.name    ) AS "index",
       group_id,
       name
FROM inf_table
ORDER BY group_id,
         name
```

(It might be more efficient to count rows when you read them in your program.)